# How to fix RAM format size?

Tags: java, android, ram

If RAM is more than 1 GB then it's not showing the exact RAM.

[image: Screen capture of the app with text like "Used: 1KB MB"]

How can I reformat it?

```
 public static String formatSize(long size) {
    String suffix = null;

    if (size >= 1024) {
        suffix = " KB ";
        size /= 1024;
        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = " MB ";
            size /= 1024;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is not clear what it shows and what you want it to show. Give an example

Comment: What is a KB? A Kelvin Byte? See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix, it should be kB or KiB.

Comment: Post full code of method please and how do you call it. Current code doesn't return anything.

Comment: Looks like you're adding suffix to result inside each `if` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private static String formatSize(long size) {
        long Kb = 1024;
        long Mb = Kb * 1024;
        long Gb = Mb * 1024;
        long Tb = Gb * 1024;
        long Pb = Tb * 1024;
        long Eb = Pb * 1024;

        if (size < Kb) return floatForm(size) + " byte";
        if (size >= Kb && size < Mb) return floatForm((double) size / Kb) + " Kb";
        if (size >= Mb && size < Gb) return floatForm((double) size / Mb) + " Mb";
        if (size >= Gb && size < Tb) return floatForm((double) size / Gb) + " Gb";
        if (size >= Tb && size < Pb) return floatForm((double) size / Tb) + " Tb";
        if (size >= Pb && size < Eb) return floatForm((double) size / Pb) + " Pb";
        if (size >= Eb) return floatForm((double) size / Eb) + " Eb";

        return "???";
    }

 private static String floatForm(double d) {
        return new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(d);
    }
```

Comment: For your information, `Mb` is `Megabit` and `MB` is `MegaByte`.